# CREATE VIEW with multiple tables - must show 0 values

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have three tables:

```
// priorities       // statuses              // projects
+----+--------+     +----+-------------+     +----+------+--------+----------+
| ID | NAME   |     | ID | STATUS NAME |     | ID | NAME | STATUS | PRIORITY |
+----+--------+     +----+-------------+     +----+------+--------+----------+
| 1  | Normal |     | 1  | Pending     |     | 1  | a    | 1      | 3        |
+----+--------+     +----+-------------+     +----+------+--------+----------+
| 2  | High   |     | 2  | In Progress |     | 2  | b    | 1      | 1        |
+----+--------+     +----+-------------+     +----+------+--------+----------+
| 3  | Urgent |                              | 3  | c    | 2      | 1        |
+----+--------+                              +----+------+--------+----------+
                                             | 4  | d    | 1      | 2        |
                                             +----+------+--------+----------+
```

I need to create a `view` that shows how many `projects` hold a `status` of `1` and a priority of `1`, how many hold a `status` of `1` and a priority of `2`, how many hold a `status` of `1` and a priority of `3`, and so on.

This should go through each status, then each priority, then count the projects that apply to the criteria.

The view should hold values something like this:

```
// VIEW (stats)
+--------+----------+-------+
| STATUS | PRIORITY | COUNT |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 1      | 1        | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 1      | 2        | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 1      | 3        | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 2      | 1        | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 2      | 2        | 0     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 2      | 3        | 0     |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

This view is so that I can call, for example, how many projects have a status of `1` and a priority of `3`, the answer given the data above should be `1`.

Using the below select statement I've been able to produce a similar result but it does not explicitly show that `0` projects have a status of `2` and a priority of `3`. I need this `0` value to be accessible the same way as any of the others with a `COUNT >= 1`.

```
// my current select statement

CREATE VIEW stats
AS
SELECT P.STATUS, P.PRIORITY, COUNT(*) AS hits
FROM projects P
GROUP BY P.STATUS, P.PRIORITY

// does not show rows where COUNT = 0
```

How could I create a VIEW that holds **all** of the priorities' ids, **all** of the statuses' ids, **and** 0 values for `COUNT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate all the rows and then get the count for each one.  Here is a query that should work:

```
SELECT s.status, p.priority, COUNT(pr.status) AS hits
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT status FROM projects) s CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT priority FROM projects) p LEFT JOIN
     project pr
     ON pr.status = s.status and pr.priority = p.priority
GROUP BY s.status, p.priority;
```

Comment: I managed to get the required result with a few changes, thanks a lot!